# Python Java Integration

Tags: java, python, voice-recognition, jpype

I'm developing a program completely written in Python but I need to integrate a Java code inside the file console.py. 
I want to integrate Sphinx4's program to give GNS3 the capability of voice recognition.

Is it possible? What do I need to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at Jython?

Comment: it allow the complete integration with all java's libraries?

Comment: Yes, because it's actually Java. It's an implementation of Python in Java.

Comment: no, this is my problem, i need java in Python!

Comment: Yes, Jython is python implemented in Java so you can use all of Java in it.  It's still Python.

Comment: I'm curious if you actually did this. did it work?